# Why does tsc -v report a different version than VS Code's Status Bar?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I am trying to figure out what version of TypeScript I am using.  In VS Code, if I run tsc -v in the terminal, it says I'm running 1.0.3.0.  However, in VS Code's status bar, it says I'm running 2.2.2.  Shouldn't these numbers be the same?  Why the discrepancy?

Answer (score 4):

VSCode includes its own bundled version of TypeScript, but is also able to use the version of TypeScript found in the local workspace. If you click the version of TypeScript at the bottom-right of VSCode, some options will pop up which let you select which version of TypeScript to use:

[image: vscode-options]

Additionally, you can configure VSCode to use a new global version of TypeScript by default. VSCode [provides more info about all this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript#_using-newer-typescript-versions) in their documentation:

> To use a different TypeScript version by default, configure `typescript.tsdk` in your user settings to point to a directory containing the TypeScript `tsserver.js` file. You can find the TypeScript installation location using `npm list -g typescript`. The `tsserver.js` file is usually in the lib folder.