# Scoping "Go to Symbol in Workspace" in VSCode to the entire workspace

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm working in a TypeScript project in VSCode that contains multiple modules. The "Go to Symbol in Workspace" (CTRL+T) command seems to scope itself to a local subset of the workspace, despite its name (which implies its search should be global).

Let's say I have `Foo()` defined in module A, which exposes a `foo.d.ts` file consumed by module B, and I have this directory structure

```
 root
 |
 +-- A (folder)
 |
 +-- B (folder)
```

I see the following behavior:

1. If I am editing a file in A and search for `#Foo`, it will take me to the actual definition of `Foo()`. Good.
2. But if I am editing a file in B and search for `#Foo`, it will only take me to the `foo.d.ts` exported by A - I have to manually navigate into A to find the actual definition of `Foo()`.

I really want `#Foo` to mean "show me all instances of the symbol `Foo` anywhere in my workspace." Is there a way to force this behavior?

Comment: Do you want to search within your project, or possibly within some packages in node_modules? VS Code quite recently changed its behavior to exclude by default files/symbols in .gitignore ([link](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/37211)). The only thing that comes to my mind would be for you to try and apply this setting: `"search.useIgnoreFiles": false` in your `settings.json`

Answer (score 2):

Preview feature:  vscode v1.45 should improve on symbol searching across javascript and typescript projects without having all the files open.  See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/11026 and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/11026 (js/ts workspace symbol search only works if you have loaded a js/ts file).

> Added with a new setting: `typescript.workspaceSymbols.scope`. Valid
>   values are:
>
> `allOpenProjects` — (default) search all opened projects for symbols.
>   Requires TS 3.9+
>
> `currentProject` — Only search the current project

- above from the first link.

> `#11026` Improved this. You no longer need to have a JS/TS file open for workspace symbol search to work and we can now search across all JS/TS
>   projects you know about.
>
> If you are using TS 3.9, all projects should be searched by default
>
> On older TS versions, only the current project should be searched. If
>   using TS 3.9, you can switch to only search the current project by
>   setting: `"typescript.workspaceSymbols.scope": "currentProject"`
>
> However we still require you to have opened a JS/TS file

- above from the second link.

Also see the v1.45 release notes : https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_45.md#workspace-symbol-search-in-all-open-typescriptjavascript-projects

> When using TypeScript 3.9+, VS Code's [workspace symbol
>   search](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/editingevolved#_open-symbol-by-name)
>   now includes results from all opened JavaScript and TypeScript
>   projects by default. We previously only searched the project of the
>   currently active file.
>
> This is controlled by the new `"typescript.workspaceSymbols.scope"`
>   setting. To revert to the old behavior, just set:
>   `"typescript.workspaceSymbols.scope": "currentProject"`.

---

To see what version of typescript you have and how to install a newer version, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39676463/836330.  And https://stackoverflow.com/a/47087772/836330 is good.

---

v1.46 release notes: [searching for symbols across projects in a workspace](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_46.md#jsts-go-to-symbol-in-workspace-includes-all-opened-projects)

> **JS/TS Go to Symbol in workspace includes all opened projects**
>
> By default, [workspace symbol
>   search](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_open-symbol-by-name)
>   for JavaScript and TypeScript now search all opened jsconfig and
>   tsconfig projects. It previously only included search results from the
>   project the focused file belonged to.
>
> This behavior is controlled by the `typescript.workspaceSymbols.scope`
>   setting and requires TS 3.9+. To revert the to previous behavior and
>   only search the current project, just set
>   `"typescript.workspaceSymbols.scope": "currentProject"`